# How to display navigation div at bottom of page under another div?

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

I have a navigation bar at the bottom of page as show in this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/4mwdkr3p/
I am trying to add another div(`<div style="display: block;" id="detail">`) exactly on top of this bar :

```
<body>

<div style="display: block;" id="detail">
<div id="detailContainer">
video
<img src="http://s11.postimg.org/hetmxqopb/main.png"><b> Mango</b><br>
<span class="centerKeyContainer">
<span class="first" onclick=""></span>
<span class="second" onclick=""></span><br>
<a href=""> mango</a><br>
</span>
<span id="FavKey"><span class="addedFav"></span></span> 
</div>

</div>

<div id="MenuContainer">

            <ul id="navigation">
                <li class="x">
                    <a title="1" href="./test.php"> <img id="myButton1" src="http://s24.postimg.org/6nv5v6uu9/worldresized.png" alt="" border="0" height="42" width="42">
                        <div class="caption">1</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="x">
                    <a title="2" href="./test.php"> <img id="myButton2" src="http://s11.postimg.org/ojkmy9aq7/flowerresized.png" alt="" border="0" height="42" width="42">
                        <div class="caption" style="color:red">2</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="x">
                    <a title="3" href="./test.php"> <img id="myButton3" src="http://s10.postimg.org/u774wlu91/moon_Resized.png" alt="" border="0" height="42" width="42">
                        <div class="caption">3</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="x">
                    <a title="4" href="./test.php"> <img id="myButton4" src="http://s12.postimg.org/7mz8gwfa1/worldresized.png" alt="" border="0" height="42" width="42">
                        <div class="caption">4</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="x">
                    <a title="5" href="./test.php"> <img id="myButton5" src="http://s29.postimg.org/jld492dn7/settingresized.png" alt="" border="0" height="42" width="42">
                        <div class="caption">5</div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

This is the jsfiddle link for both navigation div and the div above it(https://jsfiddle.net/aq13uwua/2/) but unfortunately the navigation div is not visible on both iphone and ipad screen. could any one help me fix this problem?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I am able to see the bottom bar on my mobile. Do you have any screenshots?

Comment: Thanks for reply .The first jsfiddle holds one div which is navigation bar (it is for demo to show the navigation bar).In second jsfiddle url the navigation bar is invisible! how to make it visible and move the added fav icon exactly on the top navigation bar?(https://jsfiddle.net/aq13uwua/2/ )

Comment: Okay, check the dupe. I believe that solves it.

Comment: It didn't solve the issue . After adding the images the navigation bar became invisible again!

Comment: @Paulie_D ^^^ Consider that?

Comment: @Paulie_D in that post navigation bar became visible and the added image span became invisible!